# Is this a 'legal' way to show two sets not equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

**Part A.**

Suppose that for all $x$, $x$ is in a set $X$ iff it is not in another set $Y$. Neither $X$ nor $Y$ is the empty set. And there is a background set Z in which these sets lurk and to which everything is relative. So when we say 'not in another set Y' this is a relative complement between Y and Z, not an absolute complement. From these assumptions, can we derive that $X \neq Y?$

**Proof.** If $X=Y,$ then $x$ is a member of $X$ if it is not a member of $X$ -- a contradiction. QED.

From the definition, did we prove that $X$ can't equal $Y$ and put a proper restriction on what those sets can be? Or did we show that $X$ is just not well-defined?

**Part B.** Can this method be 'scaled' to show a set V is not in a certain set R?

I reference a set of sets $R$ in my definition of a set $V$. Any $v$ is a member of $V$ iff it is not a member of any of the sets in the set $R$. It seems that, similar to how we showed inequality before, by definition, we have forced $V$ not be in the set $R$; otherwise, we have a contradiction: $v$ is a member of $V$ if it is not a member of $V$.
Here is the specific example:

For all $v$, $v$ is in $V$ iff $v$ is not in any of these sets: $(W,S,U,T)$ which form a set called $R$. From this assumption can we derive that $V$ is not in the set $R$?

And again, not being in $W, S, U, T$ is relative to a background set $Z$.

Comment: The wording of the first sentence is a bit bizarre because it seems to suggest that $x$ can belong to only one set $X$, which is already a contradiction (e.g. take $\{x\}$). . Perhaps you meant: If $X,Y\neq \phi$, $x\in X$ and $x\notin Y$ then $X\neq Y$.

Comment: All you have there is $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, mutually exclusive.  Exhaustive, too, in their union.  So $\{X,Y\}$ is a two-set partition of $X\cup Y$.

Comment: Your very first sentence makes no (mathematical) sense. Do you mean "For all $x, x\notin Y\implies x\in X$"? Or do you mean "There exists $x$ such that $x\notin Y\implies x\in X$"? Or what? You have to be more careful

Comment: @TonyK I mean x not in Y implies x in X.

Comment: For all $x$? Or for a specific $x$? I thought My question was clear.

Comment: @TonyK For all--sorry

Comment: No.  It is not valid.  It could be that $Y$ and $X$ both contain $x$.   Unless by "if" you actually meant "only if".  But if you meant "only if" then $Y$ and $X$ can each *not* contain $x$.  Unless you meant this was true for *all* $x$ in the universe.  In which case as $X$ is not empty it has an $w$ and so $w\not \in Y$. ...*if* you meant "only if".  I think the statement of the conditions need to be a *lot* more carefully thought out and written.

Comment: @fleablood This is just a way of defining a set X that contains all the elements not in Y. I word it this way to scale up to part B. How would you suggest I word this? Is what I intend clear?

Comment: The most important thing that needs clearing up is when you say "$x$ is..." do you mean that is true for one specific $x$ or for all $x$ in the universe in general.  Then when you say "$x$ is in $X$ if"  is that a statement condition definition of $X$ (i.e. $X = \{x| x\not \in Y\}= Y^c$)? or is simply and statement about elements in general (i.e. for any $x$ if $x\not \in Y\implies x \in X\implies Y^c \subseteq X$.)  Those are very different statements.  And if $x$ is *one specific* element rather than any element they are even more different.  Clear up these issues.  Then we will talk.

Comment: @fleablood: we are in complete agreement!

Comment: @fleablood It is simply a statement about elements in general (for any  if ∉⟹∈⟹⊆.) And when I sat "x is..." I mean it is true for all x in the universe in general.

Comment: Okay, so $x$ is *not* a specific element.  Then I'd say, "for all $x$ if $x\not \in Y$ then $x\in X$".  This would be equivalent to $Y^c\subset X$.  But not this is not a proof.  We could have: There do not exist any $x$ not in $Y$ so $x\not \in Y$ never happens.

Comment: I will note that if you are trying to define $X$ to be "the set of all elements that are not in $Y$", then, if $Y$ is a set, then $X$ *cannot* be a set. At least not in any axiomatic set theory that I am familiar with.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks! I specified that neither are empty. Any hints on part B?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This is more what I'm looking for thanks! What if we specify another background set V that elements x are chosen from and that we are working inside? this would then change the definition of the set X to all elements not in Y (that are still in V). Maybe there is a way to make the 'the still in V' implicit as its our "universe" (or something). How can i edit the question to reflect this so we don't run into the incident you bring up?

Comment: "then x is a member of X if it is not a member of X -- a contradiction. "  Actually this *isn't* a contradiction.  if $x \in X$ then "$x\not \in X$" is a false statement.  And FALSE statement implies something true is not a contradiction.  I am a martian if I am not a martian is not a contradiction. I'm *not* a martian so the statement doesn't apply and there is not contradiction.

Comment: @DeeDee: Just add that set. But your "definition" does not give you the relative complement, as fleablood has been pointing out: it only gives you that $X$ *contains* the relative complement, not that it is equal. Also, as he has just pointed out, for a given set $X$, if you can prove that "$x\in X$" implies "$x\notin X$", then you have not proven a contradiction about $X$; instead, what you have proven is that you can conclude that $x\notin X$ holds. This, because $(P\to\neg P)\to\neg P$ is a tautology.

Comment: @fleablood: Mind if I take a crack at answering, incorporating some of the stuff you are saying? I don't want to step on your toes if you are also thinking of going into a full answer.

Comment: @fleablood i just edited the proof. reversing the statement. Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to *define* $X = \{x| x\not \in Y\}$ then you want to use if *and only if*. But you could just say $X = Y^c$.  @ArturoMagidin ---- are you sure.  "the set of all elements that are not in $Y$" is $Y^c$, isn't it..... Unless the OP means $X$ is the set of all elements that are not members of *ANY* set.  But that violates ZFC and is akin to Russell's Paradox.

Comment: @fleablood: In most axiomatic set theories, you cannot take absolute complements; you can only take relative complements. Absolute complements are too large to be sets: they are proper classes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "Mind if I take a crack at answering, incorporating some of the stuff you are saying? I don't want to step on your toes if you are also thinking of going into a full answer."  Knock yourself out.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the case to which this question applies has the relative complement lurking around in the background. So an answer with that in mind for part A and B would be <3

Comment: " In most axiomatic set theories, you cannot take absolute complements; you can only take relative complements. Absolute complements are too large to be sets: they are proper classes. "  Ah... okay.  I've always assumed when talking of complements that a relative universal set was somehow implied if not explicitely stated.  ... Obviously when you say "if $x\not \in Y$ we have some idea what are acceptable *things* $x$ can be.  $x$ can't be my mother's suburu or Babar the elephant or "the letters that spell out what $x$ is" etc.

Comment: @fleablood edited best i could to include your comments so we can get an accurate answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me note that there are some technical issues with what you seem to be wanting to define in the first place; I'll get to them later, because I think they are not the main issue you are trying to get to.

For the sake of not saying things that are nonsensical in, say, Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, and given what you mentioned in comments, let us assume that we have some "universal set" $U$, and that everything is happening inside that set; so that when you say "for all $x$", you mean "for all $x\in U$". This is part of the technical issues I mention, and I will delve into them further below.

Let us first look at your definition: you say that "$x\in X$ if $x\notin Y$". (**Note:** *While I was writing this, it was corrected to "iff"; but since a lot of the comments refer to this version, and the paragraph after "Part B" still uses "if" instead of "iff", I will keep this.*) Remember that "$A$ if $B$" means $B\implies A$. So the statement that you are using to define $X$ is:
$$\forall x(x\notin Y\to x\in X).$$
This does not completely determine $X$. It only tells you *some* things that are in $X$. Specifically, it tells you that $X$ contains the (relative) complement of $Y$, but it does not preclude $X$ from containing other things. For example, the universe $U$ will satisfy this condition: if $x\notin Y$, then $x\in U$, because "$x\in U$" is always true, and an implication with a true consequent is true.

If you want to define $X$ as consisting of *exactly* the elements that are not in $Y$, then you need to say "if and only if", and not just "if". In that case, you would be saying that $x\notin Y$ implies $x\in X$, **and** that $x\in X$ implies $x\notin Y$. This would be equivalent to saying
$$X = \{x\in U\mid x\notin Y\}$$
in set builder notation. Because in set builder notation, the convention is that $x\in X$ *if and only if* it satisfies the given condition(s) (in this case, being in $U$ and not being in $Y$).

I will continue my answer under the assumption that this is what you were trying to give as the definition of $X$.

Now, to your method of proof: it is at best incomplete. What you are arguing is: let us argue by contradiction and assume that $X=Y$. If $x\in X$, then $x\notin Y$ (by definition of $X$), and therefore $x\notin X$ (since $Y=X$).

That's correct as far as it goes.

But now you conclude that you have a contradiction; well, not really or rather, not quite yet. What you have done is proven that (under the undischarged assumption that $X=Y$) you can establish the implication $x\in X\implies x\notin X$.

But this implication is not by itself a contradiction (a statement that is always false). In fact, such a statement is true when $x\notin X$. In general,
$$(P\longrightarrow\neg P)\longrightarrow\neg P$$
is a tautology.

So you need to take a few more steps. What you have shown is that, under the assumption that $X=Y$, you can prove that for every $x\in U$, $x\notin X$. Because you can prove that $\forall x\in U\bigl((x\in X)\implies (x\notin X)\bigr)$, and so using the tautology above you can deduce that $x\notin X$.

But this tells you that $X=\varnothing$, which contradicts our assumption that neither $X$ nor $Y$ are empty. And *now* we have a contradiction.

Where does the contradiction come from? The undischarged assumption is "$X=Y$", and so we conclude that $X\neq Y$.

Alternatively, you can note that if $X=Y$, then $x\in X$ if and only if $x\notin Y$ (by definition of $Y$) if and only if $x\notin X$ (because we are assuming that $X=Y$). So now what we have is
$$\forall x\in U (x\in X\iff x\notin X).$$
Now, if $U$ is not empty, then  *that* is a contradiction. The statement cannot hold because "$x\in X\iff x\notin X$" is always false, so provided there is at least one $x\in U$, we get a contradiction.  Note that this holds even if $X$ or $Y$ are empty, provided that $U$ is not empty.

This is fine, but you need to establish the "if and only if", not just the "if".

As to your second question, same issue: you want your "if"s to be "iffs". Yes, this is a valid method of showing something is not in a set. In fact, that is the argument used by Halmos in **Naive Set Theory** to prove that, in what amounts to a basic version of Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, there is no universal set.

To do this, he proves the following theorem:

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a set. Then there exists a set $B$ such that $B\notin A$.

*Proof.* Since $A$ is a set, the Axiom of Separation yields that
$$B = \{x\in A\mid x\notin x\}$$
is a set. We claim that $B$ is not an element of $A$.

Indeed, assume by way of contradiction that $B\in A$.

If $B\in B$, then $B\notin B$, by definition of $B$. Therefore, $B\notin B$.
If $B\notin B$, then $B\in B$, by definition of $B$. Therefore, $B\in B$.

Thus, $B\in B$ and $B\notin B$, which is a contradiction. The contradiction arises from the assumption that $B\in A$. Hence $B\notin A$. $\Box$

**Corollary.** There is no universal set.

---

Technical issues: in ZF (and in GBN) Set Theory, you cannot define absolute complements; the absolute complement of a set is never a set, because it is a proper class (it contains sets of arbitrarily large cardinality, and no set can contain elements of arbitrarily large cardinality). You can only define relative complements. Most of the time when one talks about complements, as [fleablood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/280126/fleablood) notes, there is an implicit or explicit set $U$ from which every relevant element is taken, and so we are actually working with *relative* complements. Your initial definition, in which $Y$ is a set and you define $X$ as an object with $x\notin Y\implies x\in X$ would yield a collection $X$ that cannot be a set in those theories.

Comment: Thank you! About to accept. Just wondering, do your corrections + answer apply to part B? Can we make the conclusion V is not in R if we establish the "iff"? Is this considered a form of "diagnolization" against R via self-reference?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126926/is-a-discrete-language-well-defined?noredirect=1#comment265555_126926 The motivation for this question is in the comments on my question here, particularly the last one, he says that L is not a valid set and that this is not a proof of anything.

Comment: @DeeDee: I just added a paragraph about Part B; see if it answers your question.

Comment: @DeeDee: The answer there notes that if your sets $A$ and $B$ are defined, then you can make reference to them. What you usually cannot do is define a set in terms of itself.  I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to argue or how that last comment applies.

Comment: what I'm trying to argue is that under the assumption that L is in the set referenced there is a contradiction (the one of the type we are dealing with here) and therefor L cannot be in the set referenced--and this is my proof. Nir claims this just means L is not a valid set and there is no proof. The (practically one-to-one) analogy here would be that V is in the set R because it is equal to one of the sets in V. Same deal, if L is in the set its definition references then we get this type of contradiction. And i conclude from this that L can't be in that set.

Comment: @DeeDee: I would have to read carefully what you wrote; as I note, you have a few issues with "if"s that should be "iff"s, and your argument for $X$ was not complete. The fact that you have a "universal set" to work off may make it so that you don't have a "non-object" but just an object outside your 'universal set', as is the case in the Halmos proof I've now included (which might make the last comment you refer to unapplicable at that point; that is, you don't conclude "what you have is contradictory and cannot exist", what you conclude is "what you have is not in the universe of discourse)

Comment: Sorry, now I'm a bit more confused! You said in your answer "Yes, this is a valid method of showing something is not in a set."

Comment: @DeeDee: If you show that $x\in X$ implies $x\notin X$, then you may conclude $x\notin X$. If, on the other hand, you make a construction for $X$ and you show that for every $x$, $x\in X\iff x\notin X$, then you have shown that (provided the universe is not empty), $X$ cannot exist. Those are two different things, but then it also amounts to proving two different things. Be careful about what you are assuming and what you are arguing. If from the assumption $P$ you can deduce that $X$ cannot exist, but you know that the construction is generally valid, that just means $\neg P$.